# Highlight a div on mouse down using CSS

Tags: css

Is it possible to highlight a div (change it's background color) with a mouse down event and unhighlight it when the mouse button goes up, only using CSS?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure how widely supported it is, but this seems to work (in chrome FF and Safari) at least

http://jsfiddle.net/sQU2V/

```
  <style>div:active{background:red}</style>
  <div>test</div>
```

Comment: I'll check off your answer as correct but I should have added the fact that I wanted to do this in a WebView in an Android app, where your suggestion doesn't work, nor does it work in Android's browser.

Comment: Awesome solution. I'd have used javascript for this.

Answer (score 6):

Try using the pseudo-class `:active`:

```
yourselector:active {
    background: #F00; // Or whatever
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/JEy9f/

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3aactive) it should be compatible with Chrome, Firefox and IE 8+ among others...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the `:active` selector.

[Here's a jsFiddle with an example](http://jsfiddle.net/urDhp/).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the :active psuedo selector?

So

```
.class:active{
     background:red;
}
```